# Tikz-qtree: How to make \edge[roof] width narrower?

Tags: tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

Is there a (relatively) simple way to make the width of \edge[roof] narrower when using tikz-qtree? For comparison, I'd like to make it fit closer to the text, like pst-jtree's vartri. Here's a screenshot for comparison; on top is tikz-qtree's default behavior for \edge[roof], and below is the width I'd like it to be, which is pst-jtree's default for vartri.[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-jtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Tree
        [.{} \edge[roof]; {a roof} ]
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \jtree
    \!= {}(<vartri>{a roof}).
    \endjtree
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your `jtree` code doesn't compile for me.

Comment: Not sure why; I just rechecked and it compiles for me. I don't know if it'd make a difference that I'm using XeLaTeX?

Comment: I tried with both XeLaTeX and latex+dvips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of the roof is determined by the `inner sep` and `outer sep` of the node it is on top of. If you introduce the node explicitly with a `\node` command you can add a style to adjust those values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{roof node/.style={inner sep=1pt}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Tree
        [.{} \edge[roof]; \node[roof node]{a roof}; ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you could adjust them globally for all nodes or all leaf nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\tikzset{every leaf node/.style={inner sep=1pt}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \Tree
        [.{} \edge[roof]; {a roof} ]
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: You are right (+1). The OP made an edit just when I submitted my answer.

Comment: (+1) If you want to keep the default amount of vertical space, you can change just `inner xsep` rather than `inner sep`.